# Quickbooks Error: Property IsProject does not exist. Class IPPCustomer

Tags: php, laravel-4, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am using **QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK** to integrate quickbooks in my project.

When i am trying to add cutomer to Quickbooks using following code.

```
$dataService->Add($customerObj);
```

I am getting the following exception in **sendRequestParseResponseBodyAndHandleHttpError** which is internal function of sdk.

**Property IsProject does not exist. Class IPPCustomer**

where $customerObj is equal to

```
    QuickBooksOnline\API\DataIPPCustomer (object) [Object ID #1110][75 properties]
    Taxable: (null) NULL
    BillAddr: 
    QuickBooksOnline\API\DataIPPPhysicalAddress (object) [Object ID #1115][16 properties]
    Id: (null) NULL
    Line1: (string) "a"
    Line2: (string) ""
    Line3: (null) NULL
    Line4: (null) NULL
    Line5: (null) NULL
    City: (string) "a"
    Country: (string) "United States"
    CountryCode: (string) "US"
    CountrySubDivisionCode: (string) "IL"
    PostalCode: (null) NULL
    PostalCodeSuffix: (null) NULL
    Lat: (null) NULL
    Long: (null) NULL
    Tag: (null) NULL
    Note: (null) NULL
    ShipAddr: 
    QuickBooksOnline\API\DataIPPPhysicalAddress (object) [Object ID #1115][16 properties]
    Id: (null) NULL
    Line1: (string) "a"
    Line2: (string) ""
    Line3: (null) NULL
    Line4: (null) NULL
    Line5: (null) NULL
    City: (string) "a"
    Country: (string) "United States"
    CountryCode: (string) "US"
    CountrySubDivisionCode: (string) "IL"
    PostalCode: (null) NULL
    PostalCodeSuffix: (null) NULL
    Lat: (null) NULL
    Long: (null) NULL
    Tag: (null) NULL
    Note: (null) NULL
    OtherAddr: (null) NULL
    ContactName: (null) NULL
    AltContactName: (null) NULL
    Notes: (null) NULL
    Job: (null) NULL
    BillWithParent: (null) NULL
    RootCustomerRef: (null) NULL
    ParentRef: (null) NULL
    Level: (null) NULL
    CustomerTypeRef: (null) NULL
    SalesTermRef: (null) NULL
    SalesRepRef: (null) NULL
    TaxGroupCodeRef: (null) NULL
    TaxRateRef: (null) NULL
    PaymentMethodRef: (null) NULL
    CCDetail: (null) NULL
    PriceLevelRef: (null) NULL
    Balance: (null) NULL
    OpenBalanceDate: (null) NULL
    BalanceWithJobs: (null) NULL
    CreditLimit: (null) NULL
    AcctNum: (null) NULL
    CurrencyRef: (null) NULL
    OverDueBalance: (null) NULL
    TotalRevenue: (null) NULL
    TotalExpense: (null) NULL
    PreferredDeliveryMethod: (string) "Email"
    ResaleNum: (null) NULL
    JobInfo: (null) NULL
    TDSEnabled: (null) NULL
    CustomerEx: (null) NULL
    SecondaryTaxIdentifier: (null) NULL
    ARAccountRef: (null) NULL
    PrimaryTaxIdentifier: (null) NULL
    TaxExemptionReasonId: (null) NULL
    IsProject: (null) NULL
    BusinessNumber: (null) NULL
    GSTIN: (null) NULL
    GSTRegistrationType: (null) NULL
    IsCISContractor: (null) NULL
    ClientCompanyId: (null) NULL
    ClientEntityId: (null) NULL
    IntuitId: (null) NULL
    Organization: (null) NULL
    Title: (null) NULL
    GivenName: (string) "Kuliza Technologies"
    MiddleName: (null) NULL
    FamilyName: (null) NULL
    Suffix: (null) NULL
    FullyQualifiedName: (null) NULL
    CompanyName: (string) "Kuliza"
    DisplayName: (string) "Kuliza_4something21"
    PrintOnCheckName: (string) "Kuliza"
    UserId: (null) NULL
    Active: (null) NULL
    PrimaryPhone: 
    QuickBooksOnline\API\DataIPPTelephoneNumber (object) [Object ID #1111][9 properties]
    Id: (null) NULL
    DeviceType: (null) NULL
    CountryCode: (null) NULL
    AreaCode: (null) NULL
    ExchangeCode: (null) NULL
    Extension: (null) NULL
    FreeFormNumber: (string) "2546321525"
    Default: (null) NULL
    Tag: (null) NULL
    AlternatePhone: (null) NULL
    Mobile: (null) NULL
    Fax: (null) NULL
    PrimaryEmailAddr: 
    QuickBooksOnline\API\DataIPPEmailAddress (object) [Object ID #1112][4 properties]
    Id: (null) NULL
    Address: (string) "jai.kansra+il@kuliza.com"
    Default: (null) NULL
    Tag: (null) NULL
    WebAddr: (null) NULL
    OtherContactInfo: (null) NULL
    DefaultTaxCodeRef: (null) NULL
    Id: (null) NULL
    SyncToken: (null) NULL
    MetaData: (null) NULL
    CustomField: (null) NULL
    AttachableRef: (null) NULL
    domain: (null) NULL
    status: (null) NULL
    sparse: (null) NULL
    Name: (string) "Kuliza Technologies"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I added a new library called **QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK** but before to that, there was another library belongs to Quickbooks and both have same class IPPCoustomer,
so whenever I called any **dataservice** functions it was importing old library classes. I removed the old library. It is working fine now.

Thank you